# How to send a directory to jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I am trying to send the path for my javascript folder to a template using Jinja2. The javascript folder is in the same path as the index.py, but the problem is that index.html is in the templates folder and cannot load the url. So how can I send a relative url with jinja?

index.py

```
import cherrypy
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))

class Root:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
        sidebar = env.get_template('sidebar.html')

        return tmpl.render(javascript_folder="js",sidebar=sidebar.render())
```

templates/index.html

```
 <script src="{{javascript_folder}}+/jquery.js" >
```

Comment: What is responsible for serving the JS from that directory?

Comment: Uhh, umm no clue. I just started using Jinja. index.py is in the same directory as the js folder

Comment: I found the cherrypy.url function but it says that all my css and js files are not found...... hmm weird

Comment: Well, Jinja is a template engine, and has nothing to do with serving static assets like JS. You seem to be using CherryPy as your server, you should investigate how to configure that to serve static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your js path won't change then I would just use a static path.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js" >
```

If you want to physical path to the js file to change depending on what system you're on here's how you could do that...

```
 import os
 import cherrypy
 from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
 env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))

 class Root:
     @cherrypy.expose
     def index(self):

     tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
     return tmpl.render(javascript_folder=os.path.dirname(__file__),sidebar=sidebar.render())
```

But Daniel is correct that you'll need to enable static content serving in cherrypy.  Here's how to do that...

```
config = {'/static':
                {'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                 'tools.staticdir.dir': PATH_TO_STATIC_FILES,
                }
        }

cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(), '/', config=config)
```

http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/static.html

Hope this helps!